# What does it mean when '=' is used inside a function's parenthesis (with the arguments) in python?

Tags: python, django

I came across a python code in Django in which '=' was used in an unusual way. Can anybody please explain what it means. This is the line of code:

```
return reverse('model-detail-view', args=[str(self.id)])
```

Here reverse is a function and it's value is being returned. The first argument is understandable but the second argument uses a '=' symbol. How is this working? What does it do?

Comment: They are [Keyword arguments](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments) for better readability.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In python you can omit arguments with default values. for example if your function like this:

```
def func(a, b=None, c=None):
    ....
```

you must pass a but you can omit b and c. if you want to pass only c and you can pass it with name like this:

```
func(a, c=c_val)
```

by this call python use default value for b and run code.

the reverse function get 5 argument. one argument is required and 4 is optional. this code pass third argument and left other as default. the third argument is a list.

Comment: This makes little sense and "In python you can not pass arguments with default values" is plain wrong.

Comment: Hmm, "can not" is not the optimal choice of words here. I see what you're saying now but I definitely wouldn't read it the way you intended if I didn't already understand what you were trying to say. I think you need to rephrase

Comment: "can not pass" -> "can omit"

Answer (score 0):

The call to *reverse* is passing a list to the argument called *args* of the function.